# Twitter search api in php (using curl) returns null always

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to fetch tweets using twiiter api via cURL in php with following code but it seems it always return NULL.

```
//$urlfetch = "https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q= geocode:".round($_GET['param1'],4).",".round($_GET['param2'],4).",25mi"; 

$urlfetch = "https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=Toronto"; 

    echo urlencode($urlfetch);
    echo $urlfetch;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30; // set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlfetch);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "10.3.100.209:8080");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($response);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($response);
```

EDIT: 
    for $urlfetch = "https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%20geocode:40.7,73.9,25mi"; 
    response at http://pastebin.com/jQ9S2gV4 when entered from browser using the same proxy.

Comment: Are you getting errors? A assume you are saying value for `$response` is `null`?

Comment: @MikeBrant It is not showing any error and also running this url in browsers. see response at ( http://pastebin.com/jQ9S2gV4 ). Whenver i try to access its elements it gives error trying to access non-object

Comment: @RenePot yup, the proxy is working fine.

Comment: Solved it :) Problem was that the proxy was not compatible with https url (was returning bool(false) in curl response) ,so just changed it to http.